# Getting Results in Ember Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

So it has been a long couple of days to get all the Emberjs stuff to play nice together. I really like this journey, but from time to time am beginning to feel to old to do this.

So I have a app hits the /#/Records link. From their It needs to query Rails, return the results, and then grab the show view on the other pages. 
When I had this as a single page app, with the views on the page, I had it working.... Now the last 2 days, confusion has crept in. (some extra bits in views and such are removed.

My hbs  records/index view file which is partially showing up:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">{{counter}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
      {{#each record in controller}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{#linkTo "record" record}} {{record.fullName}} {{/linkTo}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
  </table>
```

My Ember App:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember'
});
App.RecordsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});

App.Record = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    middleName: DS.attr('string'),
    surname: DS.attr('string'),
    suffix: DS.attr('string'),
})
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('records');
    this.resource('record', {path: 'records/:record_id'})
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('records')
    }
});
App.RecordsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

Comment: what type of error are you getting in the chrome console?

Comment: None that's why I can't figure it out. The basic hbs template renders its just the#each that is blank.

Comment: if you watch the network tab in chrome do you see the ajax request from your adapter? if so does it have a json payload when its returned (assuming a 200 response)

Comment: no the view isn't hitting that, and I'm not sure why. When I query the rails side via JSON is works. Only view/ CSS stuff (asset pipeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your records route to look like the below. This model hook provides you a way to specify how a controller will get it's content / model. Now when you view the network tab you should see an ajax request to fetch all the records from your backend (via ember-data)

```
App.RecordsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {                                                                                                                
        return App.Record.find();
    }
});
```