# Adding Custom Scripts to Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

So on my app, as it is loading in a table from the rails DB side, it comes in very late, and my little  $('tr:even').addClass("trAlt");  - only reads 1 tr, and doesn't apply the css class for styling. I have placed the script on didInsertElement as follows:

```
App.RecordsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'records/index',
    contextBinding: 'App.RecordController',
    didInsertElement: function(){
         $('tr:even').addClass("trAlt")
    }
});
```

But the inital load is 1 tr row (the headings), and then Ember isn't firing off the even as the view changes. 
Most of the code is the same as from this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741766/getting-results-in-ember-views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the blockless form of `{{each}}` and move the jQuery code to didInsertElement of each row as follows:

```
App.RecordsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'records/index',
    contextBinding: 'App.RecordController'
});

App.RecordRowView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'records/record',
    tagName: 'tr',
    didInsertElement: function(){
      $('tr:even').addClass("trAlt")
    }
});

// in records/index.hbs
{{each controller itemViewClass="App.RecordRowView"}}
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each

Comment: I like this idea, but Don't understand App.MyView, where did that come from? My calling of that doesn't work. I get: Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'App.MyView' ember.js:52

Answer (score 0):

Can you use plain CSS to automatically style the table?  This will apply to the rows even if they are added after `didInsertElement()` is called.

**CSS:**

```
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/itepuf/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the `isLoaded` property of controller's content:

```
App.RecordsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'records/index',
    contextBinding: 'App.RecordController',

    onRecordsLoaded: function () {
        $('tr:even').addClass("trAlt");
    }.observes('App.RecordController.content.isLoaded')
});
```